# How to show that $x/(1+|x|)$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{1+|x|}$$

$$\Rightarrow f'(x) = \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^2}$$

I understand from inspection of the graph that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$. (EDIT: Actually graph looks OK, is my answer sheet wrong?)

I can't work out how to show this using the definition of differentiability from first principles though, as approaching from both positive and negative directions seems to give the same value:

$$\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{x+h}{1+|x+h|} - \frac{x}{1+|x|}}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{(x+h)(1+|x|) - (x)(1+|x+h|)}{h(1+|x+h|)(1+|x|)}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{x + h +x|x| + h|x| - x - x|x+h|}{h(1+|x+h|)(1+|x|)}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{h +x|x| + h|x| - x|x+h|}{h(1+|x+h|)(1+|x|)}\\
\text{Can I do this??}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{h +x|x| + h|x| - x|x| - x|h|}{h(1+|x+h|)(1+|x|)}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{h + h|x| - x|h|}{h(1+|x+h|)(1+|x|)}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{h + h|x| - x|h|}{h(1+|x+h|)(1+|x|)}\\
\text{Now if h > 0:}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{1 + |x| - x}{(1+|x+h|)(1+|x|)}\\
&= \tfrac{1 + |x| - x}{(1+|x|)^2}\\
\text{Or if h < 0:}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{1 + |x| + x}{(1+|x+h|)(1+|x|)}\\
&= \tfrac{1 + |x| + x}{(1+|x|)^2}\\
\end{align*}$$

It's not clear to me whether I can do that step in the middle, but more importantly it's not clear to me how to determine from this that the function is not differentiable at $x = 0$, since this limit and f'(x) are clearly defined at $x = 0$ i.e equals 0 for both the left and right approaches.

So how to determine that this function is not differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: Difficult, very difficult, since in fact the function **is** differentiable at $x=0$, with $f'(0)=1$. Do you mean that $f'$ (not $f$) is not differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that $f$ *is* differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: $f$ is differentiable  at $x=0$ but $f'$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: Hm mistake in my answer sheet? It says "f'(x) = 1/(1+|x|)^2 except when x = 0 where f is not differentiable"

Comment: Also I feel I must have done something wrong to end up with 1+|x| +- x in the numerator as this isn't a part of the answer...?

Comment: If the answer sheet says "x = 0 where f is not differentiable", then the answer sheet is wrong. To compute $f'(0)$ from first principles, almost none of what you do is necessary. Instead, note that $f(0)=0$ hence, for every $x\ne0$, $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}x=\frac1{1+|x|},$$ whose limit when $x\to0$ should be clear.

Comment: I think we are looking at the same questions/tests/sources. I was super confident its diffable at 0, but this kept coming back so ended up here